# Google AMP: what is a layout? What is a container?

Tags: amp-html

When validating an AMP page, I get:

> Layout not supported for: container

**What is a layout? What is a container?**

Google's [AMP docs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/control_layout.html) mention:

> Make your elements responsive; include layout=responsive.

Saying 'elements' implies all elements - `p`, `span`, etc. This seems archaic - wouldn't 'responsive' just be the default?

Comment: Could you provide some sample code from the AMP page that would give that error?

Answer (score 1):

The layout attribute gives you easy, per-element control over how your element should render on screen. Many of these things are possible with pure CSS – but they're much harder, and require a myriad of hacks. Use the layout attribute instead.

Container is the element you want the layout applied to.

```
<AMP-IMG src="https://www.someimage.com/image.jpg" height="200" width="200" layout="responsive"></AMP-IMG>
```

In this case  is the container and the layout is set to responsive.

Take a look at the documentation on using layout and what all the different possibilities are and what's required for each. [AMP Layout Documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/control_layout#the-layout-attribute)